# Azure DataFactory Integration Runtime

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have manually created an integration runtime in  Azure Data Factory. I have read few articles that said - Once we create an integration runtime in Data Factory, Microsoft bills for it though there is no activity using it unless it is terminated.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure integration runtime provides a fully managed, serverless compute in Azure. You don't have to worry about infrastructure provision, software installation, patching, or capacity scaling. In addition, you only pay for the duration of the actual utilization.

Ref Azure document here:

1. [Azure IR compute resource and scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-ir-compute-resource-and-scaling).
2. [Understanding Data Factory pricing through examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pricing-concepts)

To know more about the Data Factory pricing, you could reference here [Data Factory Pipeline Orchestration and Execution](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/):

[image]

If no active executed on the IR, you don't need pay for it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm curious about this, when you create an IR, you specify the type and number of cores.  How does the scaling work then?  Are you limited to the number of cores you picked?